# UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: not animating deletion

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got an app that has a UITableView (pretty obvious, right?).

One possible action that I've programmed causes a cell (when tapped) to move from a list of "pending" items up to the list of "done" items (all items are in the same, single section). At the end of this upward animation (done using `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`), it is possible that additional items are then pushed onto the end of the list of items.

So, before the tap:

- Item 1 - Undone
- Item 2 - Undone
- Item 3 - Undone
- Item 4 - Undone

After a tap on item 3 (this is animation 1):

- Item 3 - Done
- Item 1 - Undone
- Item 2 - Undone
- Item 4 - Undone

After animation 1:

- Item 3 - Done
- Item 1 - Undone
- Item 2 - Undone
- Item 4 - Undone
- Item 5 - Undone
- Item 6 - Undone

Tapping this "done" item again should "reset" the item back to the original state (i.e., move the "done" step down to its original position and then delete the additional items).

So, before the tap:

- Item 3 - Done
- Item 1 - Undone
- Item 2 - Undone
- Item 4 - Undone
- Item 5 - Undone
- Item 6 - Undone

After the tap on item 3 (this is animation 1):

- Item 1 - Undone
- Item 2 - Undone
- Item 3 - Undone
- Item 4 - Undone
- Item 5 - Undone
- Item 6 - Undone

After animation 1:

- Item 1 - Undone
- Item 2 - Undone
- Item 3 - Undone
- Item 4 - Undone

Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [self.owner.tableViewTaskArray mutableCopy];
[array sortUsingComparator:app.orderChecklist];
NSInteger taskIndex = [array indexOfObject:self.cellTask];
NSIndexPath *newPath = [@(oldPath.section):taskIndex];


[self.owner.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.owner.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:oldPath toIndexPath:newPath];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    // Get the current list
    NSMutableArray *oldArray = [self.owner.tableViewTaskArray mutableCopy];                        
    // Process the un-completion logic
    [self.cellTask removeAutoPushTasksFromCurrentChecklist];
    // This call resets tableViewTaskArray
    [self.owner numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.owner.tableView];
    // Get the now-current list
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [self.owner.tableViewTaskArray mutableCopy];
    // Using a temp array, figure out current location of cells to delete
    NSMutableArray *oldArrayCopy = [oldArray mutableCopy];
    [oldArrayCopy removeObjectsInArray:newArray];
    NSMutableArray *paths = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (MSSTask *task in oldArrayCopy) {
        NSInteger taskIndex = [oldArray indexOfObject:task]; 
        NSIndexPath *path = [@(oldPath.section):taskIndex];
        [paths addObject:path];
    }
    // Delete those cells
    [self.owner.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.owner.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        // This seems to not be called automatically, so make it called at END of animation
        [self.owner reloadTableView];
    }
      ];
    [self.owner.tableView endUpdates];
}
  ];
[self.owner.tableView endUpdates];
```

Results so far:

1. My logic is working correctly (i.e., my data source is manipulated correctly).
2. ALL of the "undone -> done" logic works as desired (move up, then add new rows).
3. Animation from the "done" section to the "undone" section is working (i.e., animation 1 in the "done -> undone" process).
4. After the animation of the item back to its original position, the additional items it had pushed are removed from the end of the tableview, but this occurs without any animation. They simply disappear.
5. When a similar animation takes place, but the item to be removed is in the middle of the tableview list of items, the animation works as desired.

Does anyone know why an animation would be skipped just because the item(s) is/are at the end of the tableview?

Comment: Post the relevant code. Also make sure you are not calling `reloadData`. That will kill any animations.

Comment: Posted code, but it seems odd to me that this issue only presents itself in the case that the cells marked for deletion are at the END of the tableview. When the cells are in the middle, I get the effect I want. Thoughts?

Comment: Cannot find the error, but here some tips: 1) the beginUpdate/endUpdate are only needed when you do multiple insert/delete calls; not in your case. 2) make sure the paths are correct just before the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: if paths is empty, then the reloadTableView will be executed immediately which might explain your problem. 3) run in the simulator with slow animations, to see what is really happening. 4) You have a lot of unnecessary mutableCopy calls.

Comment: 1) Without beginUpdates/endUpdates, I cannot set completion block on the CATransaction, right? 2) I've done this. 3) I've done this. That's how I knew exactly what was happening. 4) As far as I can see, there is only 1 (possible) unnecessary call, when assigning to *newArray. The others are NOT unnecessary since self.owner.tableViewTaskArray is the data source for the UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in the code you posted (typo after copying?). The following line does not compile:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [@(oldPath.section):taskIndex];
```

You probably intended to write:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:taskIndex inSection:oldPath.section];
```

Which, if I understand your logic correctly, should actually use "newPath.section" instead.

My suspicion is that the paths variable is empty, or an array of nils, or only contains non-existent paths. That would cause the `reloadTableView` to be called immediate after the first animation. If that call reloads the table, then it would explain your problem.

Comment: Sorry, didn't include all information. Code isn't a typo, it's a helper method I added to NSNumber to make NSIndexPath creation easier. Probably should've mentioned that.